# SQL - Multiple Items in Query, Multiple Results in Output, Single Records on Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

A peer reached out because he has just the employee IDs of submitters on the table he has, but needs to be able to show many documents are submitted per department. I have access to a bit more, but I can't figure out to do this. Since I don't have access to his table, he gave me the list of employee IDs. The query below doesn't give the desired result, but its as close as I come. (His list of employee IDs is also much longer.)

```
select wf.department, count (empid) CT from workforce wf
 where wf.empid IN('1234','1234')
group by wf.department
```

And I'd want the result to be something like:

```
Department | CT
Reporting  | 2
```

Instead, its giving a count of one, because the employee ID only appears once on the workforce table. Is there a way to count that? Even if I can just it to list the Department next to the employee IDs like the below, I can just throw into a table in Excel and get what I need manually.

```
Department| Empid
Reporting | 1234
Reporting | 1234
```

I'm using MSSMS. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`IN` only does filtering.  If you want to multiply the number of rows, use a `JOIN`:

```
select wf.department, count(v.empid) as CT
from (values ('1234'), ('1234')) v(empid) join
     workforce wf
     on wf.empid= v.empid
group by wf.department;
```

Note:  If the values are numbers, then remove the single quotes.  Try to keep the types consistent in comparisons.